# I am getting errors trying to run SQL code designed to determine an employee_id

Tags: sqlplus

I am trying to do an if statement to determine the employee_id but I keep getting errors every time I run the program. Here is a transcript of me interacting with the database:

```
`enter code here`SQL> SET SERVEROUT ON FORMAT TRUNCATED
`enter code here`SQL> DECLARE
 `enter code here` 2
  `enter code here`3  EMP_REC HR.EMPLOYEES%ROWTYPE;
  `enter code here`4  BEGIN
  `enter code here`5  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('---------------------------------------');
  `enter code here`6  FOR EMP_REC
  `enter code here`7  (SELECT *
  `enter code here`8  FROM HR.EMPLOYEES
  `enter code here`9  WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = 5)
 `enter code here`10  LOOP
 `enter code here`11  IF
 `enter code here`12  IF (EMP_REC.EMPLOYEE_ID = 5) THEN
 `enter code here`13  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('EMPLOYEE_ID: ' || EMP_REC.EMPLOYEE_ID) ;
`enter code here` 14  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('FIRST_NAME: ' || EMP_REC.FIRST_NAME) ;
`enter code here` 15  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('LAST_NAME: ' || EMP_REC.LAST_NAME) ;
`enter code here` 16  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('SALARY: ' || TO_CHAR (EMP_REC.SALARY, '$999,999'));
`enter code here` 17  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('---------------------------------------');
`enter code here` 18  END LOOP;
 `enter code here`19  END IF;
 `enter code here`20  EXCEPTION
 `enter code here`21  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
 `enter code here`22  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('NO DATA FOUND.');
 `enter code here`23
 `enter code here`24  END;
 `enter code here`25  /
```

and here are the errors which are being reported:

```
(SELECT *
*
ERROR at line 7:
ORA-06550: line 7, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following:
in
The symbol "in" was substituted for "(" to continue.
ORA-06550: line 12, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IF" when expecting one of the following:
( - + case mod new not null <an identifier>
<a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>
continue avg count current exists max min prior sql
ORA-06550: line 18, column 5:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "LOOP" when expecting one of the following:
if
```

You can use it to determine the Department they work for, like we did in the past with a CASE.
You can use it to print a message if they make over a certain amount of money.
Maybe they are due a raise if they were hired before a certain date.

Comment: Your post is very badly formatted and I can't read out what exactly you want to say. Please revise your post and inform yourself about the formatting options provided by Stackoverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I have edited your question to try to make it into something people can understand and answer, but there are still some things you can clarify. For example, can you include some simpler, successful queries which you have done to show us what you are doing. Can you describe what you expect to see as a result of this query.